# How can I perform firebase authentication with facebook in flutter

Tags: facebook, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to add firebase and facebook authentication in my app. Facebook auth is already done:

```
final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    final token = result.accessToken.token;
    final graphResponse = await http.get(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=$token');
    Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);
    // _onGetFacebookUser(user);
```

I don't know how to perform firebase authentication with facebook result.

I've already watched [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50712363/11321310), but it doesn't help, there is only facebook login code example.
I've found [this article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/firebase-fb-sign-in-and-flutter-7ab4bdc7172e), but there is no method `signInWithFacebook`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use credential

```
final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    final token = result.accessToken.token;
    AuthCredential fbCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: token);
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((FirebaseUser user) {
      // do something...
    });
...
```

**UPD:**

It worked fine for `flutter_facebook_login` version 2.0.1
For now for version 3.0.0 there is method 'login':

```
final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
```

Comment: `The method 'logInWithReadPermissions' isn't defined for the class 'FacebookLogin'`

Comment: It was for old version. For the new one - I've updated the answer

Comment: How I can combine Facebook with the graphResponse in order to get more information?

Comment: `result.accessToken.toMap()` this can get you more information